# Detect hijacks with only content change in ClearCase snapshot view

Tags: clearcase

Normally, an update of a snapshot view detects hijacks by examining file size and timestamp. Is there a way in clearcase to detect a file whose size and timestamp is unchanged but the file content has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't taken into account by ClearCase, since it assumes that, if the content has changed, the timestamp also has.

See "[How the update operation determines whether a file is hijacked](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/how_update_hijack.htm)":

> When a version is loaded into a snapshot view, the file size and last-modified time stamp (as reported by the UNIX® or Windows® file system) are recorded in the view database.
>   These values are modified each time you check out a file, check in a file, or load a new version into the view.

#### The update operation

> When you update a view, the current size and last-modified time stamp of a non-checked-out file are compared with the size and time stamp that it recorded in the view database.
>   If either value is different from the value in the view database, the file is considered hijacked.
>   Changing only the read-only permission (on UNIX systems) or attribute (on Windows systems) of a non-checked-out file does not necessarily mean that the file is considered hijacked

The content isn't taken into account here.

The only instance where I had this case, I simply created another snapshot view and fired up a diff tool (WinMerge, KDiff3, BeyondCompare, ...), comparing the *content* of the two snapshot views.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I did. I created another view and used BeyondCompare to diff all of the files by content. I looked through the ClearCase documentation and didn't see any way to do this within ClearCase. This is definitely a step I want to add to my release procedure to guarantee that my view does match the repository.