# RAD validator checkouts files

Tags: clearcase, rad

I am using ClearCase with RAD. Sometimes I notice that RAD validator checkouts many files itself. How can I stop RAD validator from checking out files?

Comment: I see I have answered ClearCase question for you in the past: don't forget http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer if those answered were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your ClearCase version and view type.

If you are working in a snapshot view (ClearCase 7.x), and have some modified files without them being checked out first ([hijacked files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279352/6309)), RAD validator can save them before validation (which can generate a checkout first)

See if that option changes anything (as described in "[Enable or disable validators in Rational Application Developer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/enable-disable-validators-rational-application-developer/index.html?ca=dat)")

[image: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/enable-disable-validators-rational-application-developer/image002.jpg]

Otherwise, try and and override the settings at the project level:

> Projects can override the options in `Window > Preferences > Validation`.
>   By doing this, individual projects will be validated depending on the current selected  option.
>   It can be Manual, Build, and the selectable Settings.

See if by settings all validators at Manual, and then settings only one to Build, you have the same issue.
Settings progressively more at "Build" would allow you to pinpoint the validator that causes the issue.