# How do I delete check-outs from a particular view in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

I have Rational ClearCase v7.1.2.13

I need to delete certain checkouts from a view as these check-outs are reserved and the user has gone for a vacation.

Please help me.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21129391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest to do is to "unregister" the user's checkouts:

```
cleartool descr -l vob:\myVob
# get the uuid of the user's view from the description of the vob

cleartool mount \myVob
cd m:\mynewView\myVob
cleartool rmview -force -uuid old_view_uuid
```

That will not modify anything in the user's views: the files are still being modified, but they won't be considered as checked out.
Instead, they will be "[hijacked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279352/6309)" ([identified](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123318) in snapshot view) or "[eclipsed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799307/6309)" (dynamic view).

The other option (put a reserved checkout as unreserved) is rarely possible, as it require access to the view as well as elevated privileges.

Comment: Is it possible to re-register the view?
Or is there any other we to do this other than unregistering the view?

Comment: @user3437212 the view isn't unregistered: only the checkout files are: the user will have to checkout them again (again, the file themselves are not modified in any way, they just are no longer considered as checked out)

Comment: but the command 'rmview' looks like unregistering the view :)

Comment: @user3437212 not in this case: it does not unregister the view: it only removes any reference of the view (the checkout files) from the vob where you are executing the command. The view is still there and still works.