# How to resolve .checkedout file in IBM Clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

My eclipse suddenly shut down, and after that for a particular file, there are two files present:

- the main file and
- a `.checkedout` version of it.

Now the main file is not checkedout out from my machine, still if anyone else tries to check out the file: it shows it is checked out already.

I have seen from Clearcase explorer too, it is the same there.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of ClearCase (client and server, including their OS), and of the type of ClearCase view you are using (snapshot, dynamic, web view)

But in general, if a file is checked out and should not be, you can [delete any checked out status associated to your view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29169058/6309).

However, please note it will cancel *all* your checked out files done in this particular view (for that particular Vob), so make sure it won't impact your current work in progress (save it first elsewhere to be safe).

```
cleartool descr -l vob:\myVob
# get the uuid of the user's view from the description of the vob

cleartool mount \myVob
cd m:\mynewView\myVob
cleartool rmview -force -uuid old_view_uuid
```

Note: you can also get your view UUID with

```
cd path/to/my/view
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

That way, nobody else will see any of your previously checked out file as "checked out".

---

Note that a `.checkedout` file is typically the result of a failed checkout for permission issue.

Example:

```
Unable to rename "M:\myView\myVob\path\to\afile.png" to "M:\myView\myVob\path\to\afile.png.keep": Permission denied.
Checked out version, but could not copy data to "M:\myView\myVob\path\to\afile.png" in view: File exists.
Correct the condition, then uncheckout and re-checkout the element.
Copied checked-out version data to "M:\myView\myVob\path\to\afile.png.checkedout".
Checked out "M:\myView\myVob\path\to\afile.png" from version "\main\myStream\0".
Attached activity:
activity:deliver.stream_myStream.20120426.115512@\myPVob
```