# Clearcase - is it possible to create private file or meta file with read access to VOB?

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, readonly

I have clearcase VOB. We create private file during jenkins run on the VOB(dynamic view).

But recently, we need many people to access the VOB but we dont want them to have checkout n checkin, but allow their view to create private file.

Can some one guide how this is possible?

Currently developers having complete access to VOB have full permission by adding them to primary group.

Answer (score 0):

First, a private file does not involve checkout/checkin, so if you are talking about actual *private* files, you won"t have any co/ci operation to worry about.
This is different when you want to make local modification (ie modifications you don't intent to checkin ever) to tracked elements. Then you need to checkout, or to [eclipse files (dynamic views)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799307/6309) or to [hijack them (snapshot view)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279352/6309).

Second, as long as use the same dynamic view in a Jenkins job, the private files should be preserved (in the dynamic view vws storage) accross build, as long as you don't activate any "cleanup before build" option.

But if it is still not maintained, then you need to explore if it is possible to generate those private files in another shared dedicated filesystem, which would then be outside of any ClearCase view.